# Logstash Filebeat - How to detect EOF

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin, filebeat

Is there a way for logstash to be notified when filebeat reaches the end of a file? 
For example, could it send an "AT" type command to tell logstash that it has reached the end of one of its files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. The way filebeat works is to monitor specified files; often parking at EOF and waiting for appended data to ingest. The sincedb infrastructure is designed to detect changes in monitored files.